# Who am I? - a secure riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

In original form, I'm a refuge for beasts.

Cut off my head, and I can hold forth a feast.

Remove it again, and my skills I will show.

Do so once more, and to me train drivers go.

And in conclusion, though it seem rather odd-

Tie my first heads to my tail, and I shall be favored of God.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you must be

> STABLE.

The title makes sense because

> stable can be a synonym for secure.

*In original form, I'm a refuge for beasts.*

> A **stable** is where beasts might find refuge.

*Cut off my head, and I can hold forth a feast.*

> A **table** can hold a feast.

*Remove it again, and my skills I will show.*

> One who is **able** has many skills.

*Do so once more, and to me train drivers go.*

> Apparently this one's an American thing: **[BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Locomotive_Engineers)**.

*And in conclusion, though it seem rather odd-*

*Tie my first heads to my tail, and I shall be favored of God.*

> Perhaps this means **blest** (an alternative form of blessed).

Comment: Your answers appeared as I was typing mine.  For the 4th item:  rot13(oebgureubbq bs ybpbzbgvir ratvarref)

Comment: Alternative for the last line (assuming the period is included): `ST.` works as an abbreviation for someone favored of God.

Comment: @SetBigO True, but what's the "tail" in that case? ST would be just the "first heads" on their own.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's why I mentioned the period. In your first spoilered line, you ended with a period, although I assume that was just because it ended a sentence. However, if taken literally, you could call it the tail, so the answer would be `ST.`, with heads and tail included, a properly terminated abbreviation.

Comment: The current answer just throws me off with its lack of `A`, so I was looking for another take on it. Though I suppose you could just make it [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ste.) as well

Comment: Rand al'Thor is correct on the interpretation of the final line.

Answer (score 12):

The answer is:

> STABLE (stable, table, able, BLE, blest)

Comment: Gah! 9 seconds. I *just* realised what the answer must be, and while I was pondering whether or not to write an explanation first or ninja-edit it in later, I guess you posted this :-)